# React native packager cannot find entry file

Tags: react-native

My react native on windows was working for a while, but then i revisiting a not too old project. I can't get the app to load on device or emulator. The app shows a 404 and the packager keeps saying it cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots. The file does exist in the root, and the root the packager says is correct. I tried making new rn projects, upgrading node, reinstalling react-native-cli, nothing seems to work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Please be sure you launched the command line as an Administrator (su/sudo on OS X, Ctrl + X on Windows). 

I searched a long time and I discovered I tried to launch my ReactNative project with non-admin console

Comment: `npm start -- --reset-cache` and remove watchman files from your project path

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this issue with Metro Bundler.

In my windows box, I could fix it doing the following:

1. Start the emulator
2. Open **Git-Bash** window (from Git for Windows)
3. `cd /c/projects/my_project_folder/` and then run `react-native start` to start the **Metro Bundler**
4. On other cmd window, go to project folder, and run `react-native run-android`

It will build the app, install the apk to emulator, which will request **index.js** and bundler will respond just fine!